# Speed up Selenium, WebDriver, and BeautifulSoup? - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I am trying to scrape a google shopping page and have it work very reliably. The page is full of javascript(which BeautifulSoup can't parse to my knowledge) so I am using selenium and web driver to wake the page up first and then using BeautifulSoup to parse the page content. The problem is that it is really really slow. Just parsing this one page takes about 9 seconds on average and I need to parse multiple pages using the same method at once. 9 seconds for each is just too long for my application. I have done a lot of research and implemented various methods to speed up Selenium, WebDriver, and BeautifulSoup such as (cchardet) but to no significant or noticeable difference. In order to test what is slowing the operation down, I put a print in between each line and watched the prints in the terminal to see where it was getting stuck. My code is below and the slowest line by far which is causing %99 of the problem is...

`google_driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=desk&source=lmns&tbm=shop&bih=1043&biw=1866&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxh5DYj9T5AhVEsHIEHfpsA_0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAQ')`

I can't tell if the long pause in this line is only because it takes a while to wake up the page fully before extracting the contents or if it is taking a long time due to the extraction of content.

```
def google_initiate(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    google_service = Service(chromedriver_path)
    google_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    google_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    google_options.add_argument('headless')
    google_driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=google_service, options=google_options)
    google_driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=desk&source=lmns&tbm=shop&bih=1043&biw=1866&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxh5DYj9T5AhVEsHIEHfpsA_0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAQ')
    google_soup = BeautifulSoup(google_driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    google_parsed = google_soup.find_all('div', {'class': ['sh-dgr__gr-auto', 'sh-dgr__grid-result']})
    return google_parsed
```

**If it is due to the page needing to fully wake up and there are no fixes for the current set up is there an alternative way to do this that is faster? Can I do this with just BeautifulSoup because it is very fast on its own(Again the reason I am not is due to javascript on the page)?** Thanks in Advance!!

P.S. I am new to Selenium and WebDriver and really know just enough to make this work and some various modifications.

**UPDATE: - Still Stuck**

```
def home(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

    if request.POST:
        for google_post in google_initiate(request, self):
            #Do some stuff
            #Make a list
            #Append stuff to list
```

Call function at top of code

```
def google_initiate(request, self):
    self.open(
        "https://www.google.com/"
        "search?q=desk&source=lmns&tbm=shop&bih=1043&biw=1866&hl=en&sa="
        "X&ved=2ahUKEwjxh5DYj9T5AhVEsHIEHfpsA_0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAQ")
    soup = self.get_beautiful_soup()
    parsed = soup.find_all(
        'div', {'class': ['sh-dgr__gr-auto', 'sh-dgr__grid-result']}
    )
    print(parsed)
    return parsed
```

Underlying function at the bottom of the code

I'm still working at it and trying different stuff just stuck on getting seleniumbase to work with django and views. **Thanks!**

Comment: Beautiful Soup is actually much, much slower. But it doesn't render javascript so it gives the illusion of being faster.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) `pytest` test that will do that in 5 seconds or less.

Add `--headless --block-images` as command-line options to speed it up:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_parse_shopping(self):
        self.open(
            "https://www.google.com/"
            "search?q=desk&source=lmns&tbm=shop&bih=1043&biw=1866&hl=en&sa="
            "X&ved=2ahUKEwjxh5DYj9T5AhVEsHIEHfpsA_0Q_AUoAXoECAEQAQ")
        soup = self.get_beautiful_soup()
        parsed = soup.find_all(
            'div', {'class': ['sh-dgr__gr-auto', 'sh-dgr__grid-result']}
        )
        print(len(parsed))
```

```bash
pytest test_NAME.py --headless --block-images
```

I ran that and it found 88 items.

Comment: And full disclosure: I'm the maintainer of https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I am wondering if this can be applied to a Django website. I am struggling with the integration with my function. My response is delayed because I have been working to try to implement this. Does this have to remain in a class? Out of curiosity what is the "pytest" that keeps popping up in seleniumbase documentation? Am I running it wrong? I have added an "UPDATE" section to my original post where I show the way that I am currently trying to integrate it to no avail. Thanks Again!

Comment: ``pytest`` is Python's most popular unit testing framework: See https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest and https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/index.html . SeleniumBase uses it, and is flexible in that regard. There are ways of using it without using classes, but that way makes inheritance easier.